# Convertir entero de 10 digitos a formato de fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un ETL que extrae información de una base de datos, pero las fechas las muestra con un formato de número entero de 10 digitos: **1546878096**

¿Existe alguna manera de convertir ese campo a tipo date o datetime?

Saludos.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esta pregunta a ver si te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524537/convert-utc-milliseconds-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: creo que en un formato por defecto las fechas comienza en 1969-12-31
es decir a esa fecha tienes que sumarle los 1546878096 segundos y te da la fecha.

Comment: La idea es correcta, pero el valor inicial puede variar según el origen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la función `DATEADD`puedes transformar el `timestamp` en la fecha que solicitas, te anexo el ejemplo:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, 1546878096, '19700101')
```

Te anexo una ruta que te puede ayudar a comprender más el `DATEADD`. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Hola https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/80634/bdom me funciono perfectamente, la duda que tengo es la siguiente: ¿Porque '19700101'?

Comment: es el formato de fechas, anteriormente Kevin te dejó un comentario en tu publicación, donde se inicia a partir de "1970-01-01". Si te sirvió te agradecería que colocaras la respuesta como válida. Saludos.

Comment: El tiempo UTC, se considera que empieza el 01-01-1970, es decir, esa fecha sería el milisegundo 0. Esa función suma al 01-01-1970 los milisegundos que devuelve tu consulta, asumiendo que estos comiencen desde esa fecha

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
$fechaInt = 1546878096;
$fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $fechaInt);
```

Resultado:

```
echo $fecha;
// 2019-01-07 16:21:36
```

Puedes modificar el formato de la fecha como quieras consultando este [manual sobre date()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

Comment: Buen punto, el detalle está que la tecnología es sql, a nivel de base de datos

Comment: Si a lo que te refieres es mostrar la fecha con un formato de date(), esto es lo que debes hacer al recuperar los datos. Si te refieres a otra cosa, creo que no lo entiendo bien. Saludos

Comment: me refiero a que el brother que ha lanzado la pregunta no ha especificado la tecnología que está usando más allá de sólo la base de datos que en este caso es sql server

Comment: Ah perdoname, pensaba que eras tu el que ha hecho la pregunta.

Comment: nada que disculpar bro, masbien, agradezco y valoro mucho las ganas que le pones al sitio para responder preguntas, la hermandad de SOes es increíble :D